# How to retrieve category link URL

Tags: php, wordpress

Found this instruction from category.template.php:

```
/**
 * Retrieve category link URL.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 * @see get_term_link()
 *
 * @param int|object $category Category ID or object.
 * @return string Link on success, empty string if category does not exist.
 */
function get_category_link( $category ) {
    if ( !is_object($category) )
        $category = (int) $category;
    $category = get_term_link( $category, 'category' );

    if ( is_wp_error( $category ) )
        return '';

    return $category;
}
```

I'm not sure how to use it for this piece of code for links on users' pages:

```
$bp->bp_nav[117]=array ( 'name' => 'Biography'
                         ,'LINK SHOULD GO HERE' => 'LINK  SHOULD GO HERE/'
                         , 'css_id' => 'Biography'
                         , 'show_for_displayed_user' => 1
                         ,'position' => 117 );
add_action("wp","add_sextra_nav");
```

Any suggestions how to get the two working together?

Comment: I'm using wordpress and buddypress plugin. What I want to do is add custom links to user bar that take the user to adding a blog post to certain column.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to insert the category name or ID from somewhere:

```
$bp->bp_nav[117] = array(
    'name' => 'Biography',
    'category_link' => get_category_link(get_cat_ID('CATEGORY_NAME_HERE')),
    'css_id' => 'Biography',
    'show_for_displayed_user' => 1,
    'position' => 117,
);
add_action('wp', 'add_sextra_nav');
```

Example based on the examples at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link

Comment: Thanks! I tried to use this code, but it takes me back to user's profile page. I inserted the name of a column instead of "Biography" and "CATEGORY_NAME_HERE", but it still doesn't seem to work. Just the name of the column doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @pretsa Try to find out if the category-ID and category link are returned as expected: `var_dump(get_cat_ID('Biography'))` and `var_dump(get_category_link(get_cat_ID('Biography')))`.

Comment: $bp->bp_nav[118]=array ( 'name' => 'The legends','link' => 'www.mysite.com/the-legends', 'css_id' =>'The legends','show_for_displayed_user' => 1 ,'position' => 118 );add_action("wp","add_sextra_nav");

I just put the path url in the brackets there and it worked this way...